# (Noob) files in a .txt sorted out

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am a really noob when it comes to this kind off stuff. I hope I can ask this question here.

I have a text file containing 200 names of zip files and a folder containing 4000 zip files.

Is there a way to read the `.txt` and copy the 200 `.zip` files?

I searched and came up with this:

```
$Files = Get-Content filename.txt
$Dest = "PathTo:\Desired\Folder"

foreach ($File in $Files) {
  Copy-Item $File $Dest
}
```

This is `PowerShell`, so I tried that, but I don't have permission or something. So is there a `.bat` someone knows?

Comment: No one can help you, we need more information. Whats the error message. Whats the value of $file?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat it's actually clear, the person wants the batch code (even though I don't think it's going to help that much)

Comment: @HackerNCoder SO is not a code writing service. Its here to solve problems

Comment: @guiwhatsthat, I do know that, but how else would you do it?

Comment: @HackerNCoder He should give more information about the real probelm. We don't even know the error message

Comment: ***"I don't have permission or something"***?  Are you getting an error message that you could actually report to us?  (or should we guess?)

Comment: I'm guessing the error is similar to this: 'execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details'. If so please follow the advice from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613481.aspx), setting the execution policy to `RemoteSigned`, and try the `PowerShell` script again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the batch code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (myfile.txt) DO (
copy %%A insertDesiredFolder
)
```

that should work if I'm correct, else take a look here:

[For command](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

[Copy command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Comment: @user3854300 no problem, I'm here to help